# What does `text()=0` mean in TIBCO designer?

Tags: xpath, tibco, tibco-designer

In one of the TIBCO Designer `.process` files I found an expression like this: `$SomeValue/text()=0`.

What does it mean?

That `$SomeValue` is null or blank, or what?

Comment: What is $SomeValue type ? It's interesting to see full statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its evaluating the value to a Boolean.. meaning if text() is zero, then the field for which it is mapped becomes true. Generally () are not seen in the xpath values, would be great if you could post the exact statement.